# Change all font awesome 5 icons with a specific class to another FA icon - JS/SVG

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

Lets say i have 3 FA icons:

```
<i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
<i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
<i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
```

I want to change all of those to:

```
<i class="far fa-circle"></i>
<i class="far fa-circle"></i>
<i class="far fa-circle"></i>
```

This means i am modifying all of the prefix of those icons so that they change from solid to regular.

Before in FA 4.X i could just get all icons by their class name and switch their classes like so:

```
var icons = $(".icon");
icons.removeClass("fa-circle");
icons.addClass("fa-circle-o");
```

But now that they are SVG's i don't know how i can get them all and change their prefix.

I know i can change the prefix like so:

```
  if (prefix === 'fas') {

      icon.attr('data-prefix', 'far');
      icon.css({ color: "#d6d6d6" });
  } else {

      icon.attr('data-prefix', 'fas');
      icon.css({ color: "#3fcf8e" });
  }
```

I just need to know how to get all of the icons so i can just loop through them and change their prefix.

Comment: You can still just swap the classes.  Though I need to make a test case for FA 5

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m0nsajg7/1/  Yeah, you can still just swap classes

Comment: Given that they're still using classes `toggleClass()` should work: `icons.toggleClass('far fas');`. I've not tested with FA SVG though, and I know there are a *lot* of caveats when it comes to dynamically switching their SVG icons using JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand…
You can always do it using your code, you just need to replace `fas` to `far`:

```js
var icons = $(".icon");
icons.removeClass("fas");
icons.addClass("far");

// Note that this could be simplified to:
// icons.toggleClass('far fas');
```

```html
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-4oV5EgaV02iISL2ban6c/RmotsABqE4yZxZLcYMAdG7FAPsyHYAPpywE9PJo+Khy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

fas: <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>  
far: <i class="far fa-circle"></i>
<br><br>
<i class="icon fas fa-circle"></i>
<i class="icon fas fa-circle"></i>
<i class="icon fas fa-circle"></i>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using the JS / SVG version, sorry i forgot to mention that. When i would change the classes nothing would happen, i had to change the data attributes, i guess it has something to do with it creating SVG's

Comment: @RickS I've edited my answer to use the JS version. That doesn't change anything. It still works! :)

Comment: Thanks i went ahead accepted your answer since its more detailed than mine.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that i can change the `data-prefix` attribute on everything with a specific class.

```
$(".icon").attr('data-prefix', 'far');
```